# Change order of columns and rows with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with the following. I have the following dataframe in pandas:

| User | Event | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | Ev1 | 1 |
| User 1 | Ev3 | 3 |
| User 1 | Ev4 | 2 |
| User 1 | Ev5 | 2 |
| User 1 | Ev6 | 1 |
| User 2 | Ev1 | 22 |
| User 2 | Ev2 | 3 |
| User 2 | Ev3 | 1 |
| User 2 | Ev4 | 1 |
| User 2 | Ev5 | 1 |

I need it to be as follows:

| User | Ev1 | Ev2 | Ev3 | Ev4 | Ev5 | Ev6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| User 2 | 22 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I have tried with df.transponse() but I have not reached the correct solution as it is as follows:

| User | User 1 | ... | User 2 | … | N.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Event | Ev1 | Ev2 | Ev1 | Ev2 | Ev N.. |
| Count | 1 | 3 | 22 | 2 | N.. |

Comment: This is a pivot, not transpose.